# React native refresh a component when opened

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have my stack navigator as -

```
export const Routes = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
    },
    Flights: {
        screen: Flights,   
    },
    Payment: {
        screen: Payment,
    }
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'Login'
    }
)
```

The flow is Login -> Flights -> Payment.

The Flights screen makes an API call to get the flights. I have the logic to make flights call in `componentDidMount()`. However when I come back from Payment to Flights, I want to make the API call again.

My question is how do I make this API call logic everytime the Flights screen is opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to getting the data in `componentDidMount`, you could also create a listener for the [`didFocus` event](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).

**Example**

```js
class Flights extends React.Component {
  state = { flights: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFlights();

    this.listener = this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", this.getFlights);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.listener.remove();
  }

  getFlights = () => {
    getData().then(flights => {
      this.setState({ flights });
    });
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot easier with react-navigation v5 and hooks. You can use the new `useFocusEffect` hook.

> Sometimes we want to run side-effects when a screen is focused. A side
>   effect may involve things like adding an event listener, fetching
>   data, updating document title, etc. While this can be achieved using
>   focus and blur events, it's not very ergonomic.

Using the **example** by @Tholle:

```
const Flights = () => {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      getFlights();
    }, []),
  );

  // ...
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/